# Get list without JSON-like style mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am building a POS (point of sale) in python with MySQL!
I want to list all articles, but I get the JSON-like output.
My code:

```html
import mysql.connector

print('eXperience POS\nArtikli:')

posdb = mysql.connector.connect\
(
    user='root',
    password='',
    host='127.0.0.1',
    database='experiencepos'
)

try:
   cursor = posdb.cursor()
   cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM artikli')
   sviartikli = cursor.fetchall()
   print(sviartikli)
finally:
   posdb.close()
```

Comment: Can you show us what you mean by "JSON-like output"? If you are printing a `dict` , it will by default render as something that closely resembles JSON. Maybe you want to print the columns separately?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing JSON output with it printing a `dict`. Each item in the cursor returns a `dict` containing the item's fields. Since you did not show the example output I'll just use a name and description field for example. This is what I think you're looking for though. Also you may want to just loop through the cursor as printing the entire cursor would just print a `list` of `dicts` with all the items.

```
import mysql.connector

print('eXperience POS\nArtikli:')

posdb = mysql.connector.connect\
(
    user='root',
    password='',
    host='127.0.0.1',
    database='experiencepos'
)

try:
   cursor = posdb.cursor()
   cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM artikli')
   for sviartikli in cursor:
       name = sviartikli['name'] #example field
       description = sviartikli['description'] #another example field
       print("Name: {} Description: {}")
finally:
   posdb.close()
```

Comment: If this answered your question, then please mark it as the answer.

Comment: forgot to do that :)